# SQL data context with inner join

Tags: asp.net, linq

Sorry this may be blatantly obvious but I have spent all morning trying to get this working.

I am using ASP.net and have a data context as you can see below. What I want to do is add an inner join and use the company name as the search parameter rather than the deal description but for the life of me I cannot do this.

What I am trying to ultimately achieve is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Deals
INNER JOIN Companies
ON Deals.CompanyID=Companies.CompanyID
```

Can someone please help me by rewriting the below to get the same results?

```
MobileVocherDataContext db = new MobileVocherDataContext();

List<Deal> dealresult= db.Deals.Where(c=>c.DealDescription.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower()) && c.ExpiredDate.Date>=DateTime.Now.Date && c.Status==true).Skip(_skip).Take(_count).ToList();
List<CustomSearchresult> result = new List<CustomSearchresult> ();
```

Comment: Are you using Linq to SQL or Linq to Entities? What does your entity model look like? Joins are dealt with in a different way in each. Your tags are misleading.

Comment: Also, what do you want to do with the data you get from Companies?

Comment: Apologies I missed out the most fundamental point which was the WHERE clause. It should be WHERE Companies.CompanyName = "Keyword"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is Linq to Entities?

Although you should be aware of what's going on in the background, you don't need to worry about being explicit with joins in EF... unless performance is a major issue.

You can iterate through `dealresult` and access Companies as follows:

```
foreach(var deal in dealresult) {
     var company = deal.Company;
}
```

Re performance: this will execute an additional SQL statement per iteration. You can get around this by using the Include() operator (this should work in EF5 - please look it up in previous versions):

```
 MobileVocherDataContext db = new MobileVocherDataContext();

 var dealresult = db.Deals
    .Where(d => d.DealDescription.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower())
    && d.ExpiredDate.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date
    && d.Status
    && d.Company.CompanyName == "Keyword")
    .Include(c => c.Company)
    .Skip(_skip)
    .Take(_count)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed exmaple, I missed out the most important part to my question in which I want the WHERE clause to be against db.company.companyname and db.deals.ExpiredDate.Date>=DateTime.Now.Date and  db.deals.Status==true

Comment: I've added the where clause to the linq statement.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I tried this but since "CompanyName" is in table "Company" asp throws an error because d refers to table "Deals". I amy be wrong but thats how I read it. Sorry I am new to Linq.

Comment: I also tried c.CompanyName == "Keyword" but it didn't like that either saying "c" doesn't exist in the current context

Answer (score 1):

Here is some dummied up data and an example that may help you out.

```
 var Custs = new List<Cust>() { new Cust() {CustId=1, Name="Joe"}, new Cust() {CustId=2, Name="Pete"}, new Cust() {CustId=3, Name="Steve"}};
 var Deals = new List<Deal>() { new Deal() {CustId=1, Name="JoeDeal"}, new Deal() {CustId=1, Name="AnotherJoeDeal"}, new Deal() {CustId=3, Name="SteveDeal"}};

var CustomerDeals = from d in Deals
                     join c in Custs on d.CustId equals c.CustId
                     select d;

foreach (var d in CustomerDeals)
{
    Console.WriteLine(d.Name);
}
```